# Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '(UInt16, UInt16)'?

Tags: macos, swift

Why this doesn't work and produces the *"Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '(UInt16, UInt16)'?"* error:

```
func performKeyEquivalent(theEvent: NSEvent) -> Bool {
    let keyCode = theEvent.keyCode

    return keyCode == kVK_Return as UInt16
}
```

and this works:

```
func performKeyEquivalent(theEvent: NSEvent) -> Bool {
    let keyCode = theEvent.keyCode

    return keyCode == UInt16(kVK_Return)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that kVK_Return is a `#define` or const integer, and you are trying to cast to unsigned int. In swift there is no implicit or explicit cast from one type to another, even if it's about conceptually similar types, like signed and unsigned integers.

Instead of a cast, you have to explicitly convert, and that's what you do in the second snippet of code: you create a new instance of `UInt16` initialized with a a signed integer.

Comment: No implicit casts, really? I guess it's "not yet", rather than "not ever".

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, but why doesn't it say so...? Why does it say the problem is with comparing 2 vars of the same type? This should be a bug, isn't it?

Comment: There is a long, long list of compilation errors making no sense. When the error is a non-sense, usually you have to be creative to figure out what's wrong

Comment: One issue with `as` is that it is not immediately obvious how the variables associate. In OP's first example, it is not really clear whether the `as` or the `==` has higher precedence. Requiring explicit conversion instead of a cast at least fixes this ambiguity.